# jdk 1.6 to 1.7 migration

Tags: migration, java-6

We want to migrate code form Jdk 1.6 to Jdk 1.7. Would like to know if there any any changes required in the code ? Is there any checklist we can follow to ensure that there no issues during and after migration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In general, your code should require no changes. There are some minor incompatibilities, but very few have larger impact. You can read about them on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html